# How to enforce specific type on python List

Tags: python, selenium, pycharm

Lets say I have a python class

```
class cls:
      x=5
```

And I want to create a list which can only contain objects of type cls like

```
a = [obj1,obj2,obj3....]
```

where all objects must be of type cls

How Can I enforce that

Also I would like to mention the reason behind asking this question

In selenium we have class called WebElement, now a method findElements_by_xpath(xpath) returns a list of WebElemnet. So if I do it like below

```
elementlist = driver.findElements_by_xpath(xpath)
```

Now I am passing this elementlist  to function fun(elementlist ) and doing something like this

```
def fun(elementlist):
    for element in elementlist
       element.click()
```

While this works perfectly fine but as the elementlist variable in fun is of type any, pycharm intellisence does not work and no usggestion is given related to method operable on element -- which offcourse if type webElement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def fun(elementlist:List[WebElement]):
    for element in elementlist:
        element..click()
```

Try defining the type, the import you need is :

```
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement import WebElement
```